# CSS Change different properties of two elements on hover

Tags: html, css

Is there a cleaner way to do this:

```
#highlighttext:hover + highlightbox {
background-color: #0000AA;
}
#highlighttext:hover {
color: #0000AA;
}
```

Comment: If you use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), yes, as it allows nesting. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

No what you provided is the cleanest way to do that.

Comment: Shudnt this be a comment instead of posting as answer?

Comment: @Roy Looking at this now, yeah, the question is a bit off topic, and probably should have been posted to CodeReview.SE. I will delete my answer shortly.